# How to add app shields to prevent reverse engineering of Flutter applications (just like what have been done in Android)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

In Android, we not only have obfuscations like proguard or R8 (which flutter also have a counterpart), but also have things like App Shields. For example: https://appshields.com/ , https://www.verimatrix.com/products/app-shield/ . They add a shield such that it is quite difficult to reverse engineering the application.

However, how can I do so for a Flutter app? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Those kind of services do pretty much nothing and are just a scam run against paranoid people running tech companies.  They aren't worth anything against decent reverse engineers.

Comment: @GabeSechan Aha? I have heard that some shields even create a virtual machine using custom instructions (?) so imho this is quite hard to reverse engineer. Could you please explain a little more? Thanks!